# Wireless Internet not working Acer Aspire R5

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, acer

I'm so new to Linux that it should be illegal for me to post on this forum.

I bought this Acer Aspire a few months. It came with Windows 10. I obtained a virus after I removed my anti-virus soft because it was preventing League of Legends to run, you know, the way a dummy would.

I tried to removed the virus by booting first Kali Live, then Ubuntu Live from a flash drive. I wasn't able to connect to my wireless internet. The Acer Aspire doesn't have a ethernet port and I didn't have an adapter. I read somewhere that the wireless wouldn't work until I installed Ubuntu 14.04 completely. So I installed it completely, still no internet.

I have been searching like a raccoon all over the internet for some shelter from this shit storm of a problem I have. I know that I have a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6714 "chip set?".

I have tried to download the firmware directly from the site, but all there is there is a .bin.

Please help me before I karate chop this computer into stardust.

THANK YOU!!

```
uname -r =    3.19.0-25-generic


lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 =   01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0807]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Your device isn't covered in Ubuntu until 15.10. I urge you to reinstall 15.10 and then we can easily get the firmware on a USB key.

Comment: So, I should update to 15.10 then what?

Comment: Then the driver *ath10k_pci* will load and we will determine what firmware it is missing from the message log: `dmesg | grep ath`. Then I will write an answer showing where and what firmware to download on some other computer, transfer it on a USB and install it.

Comment: okay. cool thanks. I  will install 15.10 now.

Comment: okay, I'm at 15.10


dmesg | grep ath =


[    2.105402] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.315533] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.315542] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:11ad:0807.bin failed with error -2
[    2.315545] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2

Comment: [    2.315549] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin failed with error -2
[    2.315550] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch generic board data: -2
[    2.315552] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board file: -2
[    2.315553] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[    2.315554] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)

Comment: @chili555 you there?

Answer (score 2):

You lack the needed firmware file to enable your card and driver to work properly. Please download this file on another computer and transfer it to the Ubuntu computer on a USB key or similar: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.155_all.deb

Drag and drop it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer. Install it from the terminal with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot. Your wireless should be working. If not, please show us again:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Let's try a different firmware file. Please download this file on another computer and transfer it as before: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip

Drag and drop it to the desktop. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/ath10k-firmware-master/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo cp *  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo mv firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 firmware-4.bin
```

You will probably also benefit from a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_opt=1" >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: Okay. I installed the firmware, still don't have WiFi. 

dmesg | grep ath: 
[    1.953858] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.152699] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.154541] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:11ad:0807.bin failed with error -2

Comment: [    2.154549] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[    2.154842] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2

Comment: [    2.154848] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    4.281170] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff, 168c:003e:11ad:0807 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 htt 3.26 wmi 4 cal otp max_sta 32
[    4.281174] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    5.279720] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: suspend timed out - target pause event never came
[    8.351198] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c

Comment: [    8.351201] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    8.351204] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    8.351205] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    8.359939] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   13.594424] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   16.596755] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   24.899303] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   27.901566] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   36.192184] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
v

Comment: See my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: the link you provided doesn't appear to be valid

Comment: Crazy! It worked two hours ago. Until I can find the firmware again, I'm stuck.

Comment: Dang! That is crazy. When/If you find the firmware, would you let me know? Having no wi-fi is super duper lame. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have a new edit in the works. Please stand by.

Comment: any luck @chili555

Comment: Please see my edit above. Let's try the *kvalo* firmware.

Comment: [    1.926477] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.124700] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.126365] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:11ad:0807.bin failed with error -2

Comment: [    2.126369] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[    2.126989] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2

Comment: [    2.126991] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    4.256720] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff, 168c:003e:11ad:0807 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 htt 3.26 wmi 4 cal otp max_sta 32
[    4.256724] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    5.255586] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: suspend timed out - target pause event never came
[    8.329387] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    8.329398] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map

Comment: [    8.329406] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    8.329410] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    8.340390] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   13.582348] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   16.584521] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   24.903047] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   27.905567] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   36.196129] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

Comment: [   39.198276] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   47.541077] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   50.543436] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   58.833883] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   61.836336] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   70.138716] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   73.141165] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

Comment: [   81.431766] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   84.434018] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: any other ideas? This is a very frustrating problem, one that I am unequipped to tackle. I'm trying to cross the Atlantic with paper airplane technology.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but do  you have any other ideas?

Comment: I would ordinarily suggest that you compile the latest ath10k_pci driver, however, it will be extremely difficult without internet access. Can you please try the live USB or DVD for Ubuntu 15.10 and transfer the firmware files as above?

Comment: I can now access the internet with the computer because I now have an ethernet/usb adapter. I also have 15.10. What should I do?

Comment: I would run the live session for 15.10. Transfer the firmware from the USB key as above, unload and reload the driver: `sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci` and see if the wireless works. If not, check the log: `dmesg | grep ath` If it wants the -5 firmware, then I will edit my answer to update the driver.